# Oracle: get the last record which has same dates

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am trying to build a query to get the latest record which could be used in MySQL, Oracle 10 and 12.

Scenario:
I have 4 tables - customer, address, loan, application
I wanted to join these 4 tables to get the customer name and address for an application.

customer, loan and application have 1 to 1 relationship
while customer and address has 1 to many relationship.

```
select count(c.name)
from application
left join loan on (loan.id = application.id)
inner join customer on (loan.cust_num = customer.id);
```

This gives 100 rows;

```
select count(c.name)
from application
left join loan on (loan.id = application.id)
inner join customer on (loan.cust_num = customer.id)
inner join address a1 on (loan.cust_num = address.cust_num)
inner join (
select max(date) as max_date, cust_num
from address
where address_type = 'studio'
group by cust_num 
) a2
on a1.cust_num = a2.cust_num
and a1.date = a2.max_date;
```

This gives 200 records since in address for a date there are more than 1 records whose address_type is 'studio' for a customer.

How to get the latest record.

At the end I wanted address columns from address table and name from customer table for a application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For code that works in both Oracle and MySQL, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select count(c.name)
from application a join
     loan l
     on o.id = a.id join
     customer c
     on l.cust_num = c.id left join
     address ad
     on ad.cust_num = l.cust_num and
        ad.address_type = 'studio' and
        ad.date = (select max(ad2.date)
                   from address ad2
                   where ad2.cust_num  = ad.cust_num and
                         ad2.address_type = ad.address_type
                  );
```

If you are using MySQL 8+ or don't need MySQL, then you should go with `row_number()` as Tim suggests.

Note that I removed the `left join`.  The `join` to `customer` is using a field from `loan`, which turns the outer join into an inner join.  You might as well express the logic actually being implemented.

Comment: I used like this: WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a1.cust_num ORDER BY a1.date DESC) rn
    FROM application a
    LEFT JOIN loan l
        ON l.id = a.id
    INNER JOIN customer c
        ON l.cust_num = c.id
    INNER JOIN address a1
        ON (l.cust_num = a1.cust_num and a1.address_type = 'studio')
)

SELECT COUNT(name)
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;